# aMule and Deluge on Raspberry Pi

Tags: software-installation, memory, file-sharing, p2p

I'm already using my Pi as a media center, now I would also like to transform it into my download center. I've seen that both `deluged` and `amule-daemon` packages are available, but the question is, will I be able to use them both?

I have a 128/128 MB memory split, are 128 megs enough to run both **`Deluge`** and **`aMule`** even if daemonized? Anyone tried them yet?

Comment: Try it and find out?

Comment: What a smart suggestion! Thank you so much! I'll have to build a Pi where I am first...

Comment: Wow, sarcasm. What I'm suggesting is that this question is impossible to answer without *someone* doing the legwork. Not to mention being extremely localised.

Comment: In fact you are free to vote down (as you already did) or even close the question. But you are not free to tell me "do it yourself". A moderator on a Q/A site that tells to the users "do it yourself" is a serious problem. And just to be precise, I didn't ask "please somebody install these packages and tell me if it works". I just asked if somebody already did it. So you are just trying to irritate me (as you aldready did), and that's again serious for a moderator.

Comment: I'm sorry that you feel I was abusing your question, I meant no disrespect. I had no way of knowing that you didn't have access to your own Pi, and without that knowledge this question appears to be inappropriate.

Comment: As a comment, I would be very surprised if you couldn't. 128M is a ***load and there should be a lot left over. Unless you run Java ;) Heavy file and IO activity on fairly slim processor without abundant cache RAM might be intense, though. How fast is fast is a matter of taste.

Comment: +1 for the terrible attitude on "Try it and find out".
This is the true description of useless entropy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you some other alternative: use mldonkey.

> sudo apt-get install mldonkey-server

It has torrent and donkey protocols in a light daemonized server, that you can access via a HTTP connection using a browser, even from remote machines.